# Recibo un objeto vacio {}

Tags: javascript, php, nodejs, formularios, fetch

Buenas un "pequeño" prblema. Estoy intentando relacionar, un formulario que elaboré, con una base de datos de mysql y nodejs . El inconveniente surge cuando intento enviar esos datos. Si lo intento desde la base misma no hay problemas, se envia completamente, ahora cuando la envio por el formulario, se envia un objeto vacio adjunto cod.Gracias de antemano!

(Rutas)

```javascript
    // Utilizar Express
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const controller = require('../controllers/index.controller');

// GET
router.get('/', controller.index)
// POST
router.post("/add-user",(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.body)
})
router.post("/update-user/:userId",controller.updateUser)

// DELETE
router.delete("/delete-user/:userId",controller.deleteUser)
module.exports = router
```

(scripts del formulario)

```
form.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
const datos = new FormData(form);
const send = document.getElementById("sending")
const formValues = Object.values(campos)
const valid = formValues.findIndex(value => value == false)
if(valid == -1){
    send.classList.add("sending")
    fetch("/add-user",{
        method:"POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: datos.get("name"),
            surname: datos.get("surname"),
            email: datos.get("email")
        }),
        headers:{
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())
}

})
```

Comment: y por que no simplemente envías el FormData -> `body: JSON.stringify(datos)`?

Comment: En un primer momento eso hice :( , asi que para verlo por la consola del navegador deicidí ser mas especifico a ver que tal y en efecto se muestran los datos pero no se aprecian en la terminal

Comment: no tienes ningún error en la consola?

Comment: {}
{ name: 'Carlo', surname: 'safads', email: 'Carlomagno@gmail.com' }, No. ni en la terminal ni en la consola,así se ve cuando intento por el formulario y por la base de datos, respectivamente.Ya revisé que los name coincidieran con los del crud pero tampoco es el problema.

Comment: Ché descubrí algo,si lo mando atraves de un action sí se envia

Comment: un poco raro, no soy experto en JS ni en Node por lo que poco puedo ayudar aquí, lo siento

Comment: Para poder recibir datos desde el cliente que vengan en JSON o desde un formulario, necesitas usar un analizador para el cuerpo de la solicitud. En Express dispones de los siguientes middleware: [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) y [`express.urlencoded()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded). Ambos debes ejecutarlos antes de cualquier otro middleware de manejo de rutas. Saludos

Comment: Justamente me faltaba express.json() TY <3